# Convert function not working with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime field named SUBMISSION_DATE which I am converting into MM/DD/YYYY format. I am using SQL Server.

Problem is when I am fitering data using SUBMISSION_DATE, I am not seeing expected data.

I am creating a table using above query output, and I am not able to get correct data when I apply where clause on SUBMISSION_DATE.

```
 Select x.* from  

 (     
 Select Id, Convert(varchar,SUBMISSION_DATE_CX,101) as Sub_Date,     
 Total_Loan_Amount     
 FROM  M     
 where SUBMISSION_DATE_CXis not null    
  ) [x]

 where [x].Sub_Date>= '1/1/2019'
```

Comment: Because you are comparing `varchar` not `date`. add that where clause to the sub-query. Why do you have the sub-query at all? You could remove it all together.

Comment: What's the "expected data"? You are converting the `DATE` into a `VARCHAR`, and then you are comparing. I doubt you'll get any meaningful result.

Comment: And if you are going to use date strings you should use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD format. The one you have here is ambiguous and can get dates incorrect based on languages settings of the connection.

Comment: Thanks, I can remove subquery which is okay, I was just trying in different way. I tried Format(data, 'MMDDYYYY') but still could get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you are comparing `varchar` not `date`. Here's an example of the differences.

```
select 1 where '1/1/2019' > '12/29/2018' 
select 1 where cast('20190101' as date) > cast('20181221' as date)
```

The first one is comparing the literal text where as the second is comparing dates.

You can remove the sub-query since it is useless here, or add the `where` clause to your sub-query

```
 Select x.* from  
 (     
 Select Id, Convert(varchar,SUBMISSION_DATE_CX,101) as Sub_Date,     
 Total_Loan_Amount     
 FROM  M     
 where SUBMISSION_DATE_CXi >= '20190101' 
  ) [x]

Select 
    Id, 
    Convert(varchar,SUBMISSION_DATE_CX,101) as Sub_Date,     
    Total_Loan_Amount     
 FROM  M     
 where 
    SUBMISSION_DATE_CX >= '20190101'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for my purpose I want to put output of this query into a table from where I can pull and join it to other date dimension table.

Comment: I don't understand, you hard coded the where clause in your original post... how is this any different?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write this?

```
Select Id, Convert(varchar(255), SUBMISSION_DATE_CX, 101) as Sub_Date,     
       Total_Loan_Amount     
from m   
where SUBMISSION_DATE_CX >= '2019-01-01' ;
```

The problem with your code is that you are doing *string* comparisons, not *date* comparisons.  However, all that extra stuff is unnecessary.  Simplifying the query should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You must compare dates and not strings:

```
Select x.Id, x.Sub_Date, x.Total_Loan_Amount from (     
  Select Id,  
  SUBMISSION_DATE_CX,
  Convert(varchar,SUBMISSION_DATE_CX,101) as Sub_Date,     
  Total_Loan_Amount     
FROM  M     
where SUBMISSION_DATE_CX is not null    
) x
where x.SUBMISSION_DATE_CX >= DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Since I am going to join result of this query to a field (MM/DD/YYYY) in Date Dimension table, so I don't want to hard code anything in where clause.

Comment: @Shenk There is nothing more hardcoded than the code in your question. This returns the same columns like your question but the order of the rows is the right one.